# captureStream from transferred canvas not working in firefox

Tags: firefox, html5-canvas, mediastream, offscreen-canvas, capturestream

Let's say I have a canvas:

```
<canvas height="500" width="500"></canvas>
```

I can capture a video from it using [captureStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream).

So if I have a video element, I can pass it the captured stream and see whatever I draw mirrored in the video:

```
<video autoplay height="500" width="500"></video>


const video = document.querySelector("video");
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

const stream = canvas.captureStream(25);
video.srcObject = stream;
video.play();
```

I can also derive an [OffscreenCanvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas) from this canvas, and transfer to another frame

```
const iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");
const offscreen = canvas.transferControlToOffscreen();

iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(
  {
    type: "canvasTransfer",
    canvas: offscreen
  },
  "*",
  [offscreen]
);
```

And perform the drawing operation from within a sandboxed iframe.

This seems to work fine in chrome but in firefox captureStream fails and I get following error:

```
[Exception... "Component not initialized"  nsresult: "0xc1f30001 (NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED)"  location: "JS frame :: https://2rlmz5.csb.app/src/index.js :: $csb$eval :: line 16"  data: no]
```

Is there a known resolution ? Any help is highly appreciated.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-browser-2rlmz5?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1257440) in Firefox related to this. As for now, in Firefox, the `captureStream` will throw if the `canvas` context is not initialized. A `getContext` call, before invoking `captureStream`, fixes that error:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

canvas.getContext('2d');

const stream = canvas.captureStream(25);
```

```html
<canvas height="500" width="500"></canvas>
```

But, the problem here is that the `transferControlToOffscreen` does not work if the canvas context is initialized, and vice-versa if `transferControlToOffscreen` was invoked first, then canvas context can be initialized only in offscreen.
Thus, the only resolution is to wait for that bug to be fixed.

Comment: One ugly workaround would be to regularily send ImageBitmaps from the OffscreenCanvas to the main window, paint these on an ImageBitmapRenderer context and capture the MediaStream from its canvas.

Comment: POC: https://jsfiddle.net/9ug4k8am/ (unrelated, but this fiddle exposes a new bug in FF where `fillStyle` is ignored, I'll leave it broken for posterity...)

Comment: Oh wow, open since 7 years. Thanks a lot for your explanation and the workaround.